# WPF LINQ to SQL Class customization

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 and SQL Server Express 2014, writing a WPF application using LINQ to SQL to access the data.  My intent is full CRUD capabilities, using various UI elements mapped to observableCollections.  So far everything works well but I am just using the individual tables mapped to datagrid.  I want to present a single datagrid with the results of a left join from two of the tables, so in the dbml layout I created a new table, and used a stored procedure as the data source IDE generated code looks like this:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.ListAllDocuments")]
public partial class TrackDocument : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{ // innards removed for readability }
```

When I run this I get an unhandled exception "Invalid object name 'dbo.ListAllDocuments'" . . . this is the stored procedure with the Left Join statement.  How do I go about adding the query language to the class I built to represent this data?  Here is the observable class with constructor that I modeled with the single table case for eventual binding to UI:

```
class ObservableTrackDocument : ObservableCollection<TrackDocument>
{
    public ObservableTrackDocument(DocControlClassesDataContext dataDc)
    {
        foreach (TrackDocument tDoc in dataDc.TrackDocuments)
        {
            this.Add(tDoc);
        }
    }
}
```

But the datacontext is not filled for the table because the stored procedure can't be used as the source.  It occured to me that I needed to add the LINQ query in the constructor here and then do the foreach loop to fill the observableCollection: something like this:

```
class ObservableTrackDocument : ObservableCollection<TrackDocument>
{
    public ObservableTrackDocument(DocControlClassesDataContext dataDc)
    {
        var query = from f in dataDc.FilesTransmitteds
                    from r in dataDc.FilesReturneds
                    .Where(x => f.DocumentNumber == x.DocumentNumber && f.REV == x.REV)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { (list of fields) };
        foreach (TrackDocument tDoc in query)
        {
            this.Add(tDoc);
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work either (I remvove the "Source" reference to the stored procedure for the TrackDocument class property list in the dbml layout which was the cause of the original exception) . . . The compiler cannot reconcile casting the query items to TrackDocument class for some reason.

Do I need to override one of the IDE generated methods in the TrackDocument class to execute the query that in the ordinary single table case would result in a TrackDocuemnts collection?  If so, can you give me an example of how to override?  The class code is in an autogenerated file so I know I can't manually add things there . . .

I hope this is clear . . . I'm confused about the language to describe these things.

Thanks, Paul

Comment: I think you'll want to associate the stored procedure with a function using the System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute.

Comment: @juharr I interpret what you say as add the stored procedure to the DataContext by dragging it into the designer layout . . . which I have done.  It shows up as a method, and can be associated with the behavior of a class but only as an insert, delete, or update.  If I manually change the designer.cs file then it gets overwritten as it is auto-generated from by the IDE.  So I'm not sure what exactly you mean . . . sorry to be obtuse :)

Comment: @juharr I have tried to change the line to ` [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name = "dbo.ListAllDocuments")]` but the compiler tells me this is only appropriate for methods . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul,

Try using a view instead of a stored procedure.  This will give you table-like functionality with Linq.

If you must use a stored procedure, that is returning a data set, you need to create an entity for the stored procedure's return type.  When clicked on the stored procedure in the DBML designer, check your properties for "Return Type" (this is the Class/Table that will receive the data returned from the SPROC).

For Example, if your Stored Procedure was:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_ObservableTrackDocuments
  @documentNumber int
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT A,B,C
  FROM FilesTransmitted, FilesReturned
  WHERE DocumentNumber = @documentNumber
END
```

You can create the same context as a view:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_ObservableTrackDocument
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT A,B,C
  FROM FilesTransmitted, FilesReturned
END
```

The view can be dragged and dropped from the server explorer to your dbml and will operate as a table.  This way you can query from code with:

```
var otd = vw_ObservableTrackDocuments.Where(x => x.DocumentNumber = "123").ToList();
```

This will return you a list of your results by DocumentNumber 123, without having to manually manipulate the Linq generated code.

Comment: can you give an example?  I'm not tied to the stored procedure, in fact think it is better to find a way to explicitly query, at lest for developing my understanding about what is actually going on.

Comment: I posted what I have working . . . not sure it's going to pan out.  But I also changed the return type for the SP, to no avail, as I am still not able to create a DataContext Table with the SP.

Comment: Paul, sorry for the extreme delay... duty calls.  I have modified my response to hopefully clarify on your questions.  Concerning the SP, the return type must reflect what is coming back fro the SP.  If your SP returns Document, Name, Date, ..., then you must add an entity that hold those fields and data types for Linq to map to.  In the GUI designer, you can right click > new > entity and generate a custom "table" that holds your results.  Again this can lead to data type issues, so best bet is to attempt a view that can map directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have now, and is working:

```
class tdoc
{
    public int xID {get; set;}
    public int TransID { get; set; }
    public System.String TransmittalName { get; set; }
    public System.String FileName { get; set; }
    public System.String DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    public System.String REV { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime REVDate { get; set; }
    public System.String Title { get; set; }
    public int? rID { get; set; }
    public int? CODE { get; set; }
    public System.String RTNTrans { get; set; }
    public System.String RtnFile { get; set; }
}

class ObservableTrackDocument : ObservableCollection<TrackDocument>
{
    public ObservableTrackDocument(DocControlClassesDataContext dataDc)
    {
        IEnumerable<tdoc> query = from f in dataDc.FilesTransmitteds
                                           from r in dataDc.FilesReturneds
                                           .Where(r => f.DocumentNumber == r.DocumentNumber && f.REV == r.REV)
                                           .DefaultIfEmpty()
                                           select new tdoc
                                           {
                                               xID = f.UID,
                                               TransID = (int)f.TransID,
                                               TransmittalName = f.TransmittalName,
                                               FileName = f.FileName,
                                               DocumentNumber = f.DocumentNumber,
                                               REV = f.REV,
                                               REVDate = (System.DateTime)f.REVDate,
                                               Title = f.Title,
                                               rID = r.UID,
                                               CODE = r.CODE,
                                               RTNTrans = r.RTNTrans,
                                               RtnFile = r.FileName
                                           };
        foreach (tdoc Doc in query)
        {
            TrackDocument d = new TrackDocument();
            d.xID = Doc.xID;
            d.TransID = Doc.TransID;
            d.TransmittalName = Doc.TransmittalName;
            d.FileName = Doc.FileName;
            d.DocumentNumber = Doc.DocumentNumber;
            d.REV = Doc.REV;
            d.REVDate = Doc.REVDate;
            d.Title = Doc.Title;
            d.rID = Doc.rID;
            d.CODE = Doc.CODE;
            d.RTNTrans = Doc.RTNTrans;
            d.RtnFile = Doc.RtnFile;
            this.Add(d);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a TrackDocument class as part of the DataContext.  In order to query with the join I had to create an equal class outside of the DataContext to query into (else I get a "Explicit construction of Entity Type xxx is not allowed in query" exception) and then I copy into and fill my observableCollection with the DataContext class.  This seems kind of backwards . . . isn't there a better way?